# Como separar un dataframe de asfreq

Tags: python

Hola amigos esta pregunta viene de una pregunta anterior, tengo el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd

lista_a=['2009-09-15','2009-09-17','2009-09-20','2009-09-25']
lista_b=[-0.56,1.53,2.65,0.34]

df = pd.DataFrame({'valor': lista_b}, index=lista_a)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.asfreq(freq='D')
print(df)
```

Lo que hace el código es buscar fechas faltantes en la lista_a y rellenarlos con un Nan en la lista_b.

Me da como resultado:

```
            valor
2009-09-15  -0.56
2009-09-16    NaN
2009-09-17   1.53
2009-09-18    NaN
2009-09-19    NaN
2009-09-20   2.65
2009-09-21    NaN
2009-09-22    NaN
2009-09-23    NaN
2009-09-24    NaN
2009-09-25   0.34
```

En el ultimo dataframe estoy tratando de dividirlo en dos columnas por que están combinadas
ambas en una sola. Deseo hacer un grafico de barras con ambas columnas, pero no puedo separarlos.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Buen día, si te refieres a que la "columna" donde están las fechas no tiene nombre y parece que está dentro de la columna de `valor` entonces hace falta comprender como funcionan los `dataframes`, esa "columna" es un índice. Tu `dataframe` se conforma por una columna y un nivel de índices (Puede haber multi índices).

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, ¿podría convertir esos índices en una columna?

Comment: Recuerda que parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que los usuarios hagan un intento por resolver sus dudas, una búsqueda de 2 segundos en Google te da ejemplos y un enlace a la documentación de `pandas`. Puse una respuesta un poco más completa explicando un método de hacerlo y también como utilizar los índices de forma directa ya que esa comparación no viene tal cual en la documentación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Los `dataframes` se componen por una tabla con celdas donde la primera fila son los nombres de las columnas y la primer columna son los índices. Esto permite localizar celdas a través de un sistema similar a coordenadas utilizando las funciones [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) y [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), ejemplo:

```
df.loc['2009-09-15','valor']
```

También es posible obtener el valor de alguna celda utilizando "filtros"

```
df['valor']['2009-09-15']
```

**Nota:** Te recomiendo leer las secciones de la documentación que puse para entender la diferencia entre `loc`, `iloc` y filtros.

Si queremos utilizar únicamente la "columna" con los índices, entonces utilizamos:

```
df.index
```

Que en tu caso al imprimir la línea anterior obtendríamos lo siguiente:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2009-09-15', '2009-09-16', '2009-09-17', '2009-09-18',
               '2009-09-19', '2009-09-20', '2009-09-21', '2009-09-22',
               '2009-09-23', '2009-09-24', '2009-09-25'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Por lo que para hacer gráficas o cálculos podemos utilizar `df.index` y `df['valor']` que serían dos "columnas" (Recuerda, la primer "columna" se llama "índices", por lo que lo correcto sería decir que utilizamos los índices y la columna `valor`).

Ahora, si por alguna razón quisieras convertir los índices a una nueva columna podrías utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), esto crearía un nuevo índice y el índice actual lo convertiría en una columna (Esto es por defecto, hay otros métodos, lee la documentación que puse sobre `reset_index`).

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

lista_a=['2009-09-15','2009-09-17','2009-09-20','2009-09-25']
lista_b=[-0.56,1.53,2.65,0.34]

df = pd.DataFrame({'valor': lista_b}, index=lista_a)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.asfreq(freq='D')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={"index": "fecha"}, inplace=True)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    fecha       valor
0   2009-09-15  -0.56
1   2009-09-16  NaN
2   2009-09-17  1.53
3   2009-09-18  NaN
4   2009-09-19  NaN
5   2009-09-20  2.65
6   2009-09-21  NaN
7   2009-09-22  NaN
8   2009-09-23  NaN
9   2009-09-24  NaN
10  2009-09-25  0.34
```

**Nota adicional:** Hay `dataframes` con multiples niveles de nombres de columnas así como de índices, para trabajar con ellos puedes revisar la [documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).